# Wordpress database error: [Query was empty] - using $wpdb->prepare()

Tags: plugin-development, database, mysql, wpdb

I have edited my question, I'm now getting the error about checking my MySQL settings. I changed the $sql_dvalues variable to an array with the values instead of comma spaced values and now it is saying the following:

> **WordPress database error:** [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3]
>
> > INSERT INTO wp_efpd_gmaps ( time, name, address, description, title ) VALUES ( '2011-10-30 08:48:32', 'test', 'tedst', 'tedst', 'tedst' ),

The reason I'm using `$wpdb->prepare()` is because I read this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb under the headline `Protect Queries Against SQL Injection Attacks` but maybe I read wrong and don't need to use that? I'm not sure, some advice would be appreciated.

---

## Older notes & code:

I have set up a way to add stuff into a WP database a little simpler and without having to know SQL, and I'm running into a problem. The query code outputs fine (see code below, `die($str);`) but whenever I try to actually test it by adding some data it gives me the following error:

> **WordPress database error:** [Query was empty]

It was working at one point but not inserting any data, and giving me a different error telling me to check my MySQL settings or something on what to use after ", I don't really remember what that said but I want to fix this problem first.

Here's my function in my class called `Efpd2`

```
public function efpd_prepare_db($data=array(),$table_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.$table_name;
    
    $datenow = date('Y\-m\-d H\:i\:s');
    
    $sql_values = 'time, ';
    $sql_cvalues = '%s, ';
    $sql_dvalues = array($datenow);
    $int=0; $dcount = count($data);
    foreach($data as $dat){
        $int++;
        $sql_values .= $dat['name'];
        if($int!=$dcount){
            $sql_values .= ", ";
        }
        $sql_cvalue .= $dat['type'];
        switch($dat['type']){
            case 'txt': $sql_cvalues .= '%s'; break;
            case 'num': $sql_cvalues .= '%d'; break;
            case 'float': $sql_cvalues .= '%f'; break;
            default: die('Error writing to database, wrong value type. Use \'num\', \'float\' or \'txt\'.');
        }
        if($int!=$dcount){
            $sql_cvalues .= ", ";
        }
        array_push($sql_dvalues,$dat['value']);
    }
    
    $str = " 
    INSERT INTO $table_name
    ( $sql_values )
    VALUES ( $sql_cvalues ),
    $sql_dvalues
    ";
    // For debugging, use this:  die($str);
    //die($str);
    
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            INSERT INTO $table_name
            ( $sql_values )
            VALUES ( $sql_cvalues ),
        ",
        $sql_dvalues
    ) );
}
```

And the code I'm using to add the data:

```
function add_sample_data(){     
    $efpd = Efpd2::efpd_prepare_db(
    array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'name', // Name of the variable inside the table
            'value' => 'test', // Value to add
            'type' => 'txt' // Type of data to be added ('num' = %d, 'txt' = %s, 'float' = %f). See $wpdb->prepare() documentation on codex.wordpress.org
        ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'address',
            'value' => 'tedst',
            'type' => 'txt'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'name' => 'description',
            'value' => 'tedst',
            'type' => 'txt'
        ),
        3 => array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'value' => 'tedst',
            'type' => 'txt'
        )
    ),
    'efpd_gmaps'); // Table to add data to
    unset($efpd);
}
add_action('init','add_sample_data');
```

And this is what is sent out when using `die($str);` in `Efpd2::efpd_prepare_db()`:

> INSERT INTO wp_efpd_gmaps ( time, name, address, description, title ) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ), '2011-10-30 07:27:53', 'test', 'tedst', 'tedst', 'tedst'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware that `$wpdb->insert` does exactly this?

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'table', // Table name
    array(
        'column' => 'foo',
        'field' => 1337,
    ), // Columns
    array(
        '%s',
        '%d',
    ) // Explicit formatting
 );
```

**Right?**

Comment: I was actually focusing more on the text under the headline `Protect Queries Against SQL Injection Attacks` on this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb but maybe I read wrong and don't need to use that? I'm not sure, some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: $wpdb->insert escapes everything itself. You don't need to use ->prepare unless you use ->query which is manually constructed by you and needs to be escaped.

Comment: Alright, thank you. :) Seems to work fine, I just wasn't 100% sure what approach to take and I guess I took the wrong one first!